# Sequence of irrational numbers

Tags: analysis, proof-verification

I have to show that:

If $x$ is an real number, there is a sequence of irrational numbers converging to $x$.

My attempt:

We know that every $x$ real is an accumulation point of the irrational numbers,then if we define a sequence in the irrational numbers there exists an $x$ real such that its neighborhood contains infinitely points of the sequence defined.

Am I right?, Do I have to construct a sequence? or I can prove it like this Is because I do not know how to explain it. Thank you, I need your help :)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**
$$ a_n = \frac{\left\lfloor nx\right\rfloor}{n}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}.$$

Comment: Thank you @JackDAurizioThen do my answer is incomplete ?or is in a good way

Comment: It is a good argument: both $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ are dense in $\mathbb{R}$, hence for any real number $x$ there exist a sequence of rational numbers converging towards $x$, and a sequence of irrational numbers converging towards $x$. My hint just gives an explicit sequence in $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ converging towards $x$.

Comment: Good, and thank you :) but do I can leave it like this or I have to fix something?

Comment: It looks just fine to me.

Comment: Uff thank you a lot because I thought that I had to use fancy math or modify something :)

Comment: Then this proof is done :)